# JSpdf@2.3.1 is not loading on stackblitz

Tags: angular8, jspdf, stackblitz

i am working on a angular8+ project and older versions like (jspdf@1.4.1) working fine in stackblitz but latest versions are not working.
[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-jspdf-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

if i click on `install missing packages` , am getting the following error `unable to find worker threads on npm registry` ?
[image]

can some one help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install worker-thread package,
Enter the correct package name in the left navigation where to input package name.
Package name is: worker-thread not worker_threads or worker_thread

Comment: I also have this issue. And the suggestion to install the `worker-thread` package didn't work for me .

Comment: The above solution didn't work for me too.